# PHP File Upload greater than upload_max_filesize and error

Tags: file-upload, php

How can I catch an error on a file uploaded to my web server that is greater than php upload_max_filesize?

My question is similar to [so/large-file-upload-errors-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757111/large-file-upload-errors-with-php) although my memory limit is set to 512M so the resolution that question used will not help me.

I am trying to upload a file 6.9MB for example and my upload_max_filesize = 6M.  My script basically just stops executing and I cannot tell where or why.  Also, I have error reporting turned on.

Also I should note that files <6MB I can upload and process correctly with the following code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) and !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

    $info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']); 
    $ext = $info['extension'];
    //verify file is of allowed types 
    if(Mimetypes::isAllowed($ext)){
        if(filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) <= AttachmentUploader::$maxFilesize){              
            $a = new AttachmentUploader();      //for file uploading 
            if($a->uploadFile($_FILES['file'], 'incident', $_POST['sys_id'])){
                header("location: ".$links['status']."?item=incident&action=update&status=1&place=".urlencode($links['record']."id=".$_POST['sys_id']));            
            }else{
                header("location: ".$links['status']."?item=incident&action=update&status=-1&place=".urlencode($links['record']."id=".$_POST['sys_id']));           
            }

        }else{      
            $errors[] = 'The file you attempted to upload is too large.  0.5MB is the maximum allowed size for a file.  If you are trying to upload an image, it may need to be scaled down.';
        }
    }else{
        $errors[] = 'The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.  Acceptable extensions: jpg, gif, bmp, png, xls, doc, docx, txt, pdf';
    }
}else{
    $errors[] = 'Please attach a file.';
}
```

My php.ini settings:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 7200     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
memory_limit = 512M  ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 6M
```

Comment: Does your webserver log any errors? Are you over `max_input_time`?

Comment: I cannot fathom I am over max input time as I am on a gigabit lan to the server and a file > 6MB is going almost instantly.  I will check into it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in `$_FILES['userfile']['error']`. You just have to check that this value is `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` to detect if the file is bigger than the max size defined in your php.ini.

---

**Resources :**

- [php.net - File upload, Error Messages Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: Is it always 'userfile' or would it be the name of the input field ?

Comment: It's based on the field name. For you it will be `$_FILES['file']['error']`

Comment: After checking the submit was pressed I have if($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){echo "error";}else{echo "no error";} my script is not echoing either value.

Comment: Check that the post_max_size is larger than upload_max_filesize. If these values are the same and the file exceeds the limit, it will cause the $_FILES array (and $_POST) to be empty. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size