# PHP Upload images with width greater than 2000 pixels causes crash

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, upload

When users upload an image to my server (Shared Server), the server shoots an error when the file has a width > 2000 pixels. It doesn't have to do with the filesize -- I can upload a 1 mb file at 2000 width and it still crashes. If I upload a 1 mb file at 1000 pixels, it works fine.

This is the error I get.
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20000 bytes)

I am using SimpleImage plugin (http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) and CakePHP framework.

I read both [PHP File Upload greater than upload_max_filesize and error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762467/php-file-upload-greater-than-upload-max-filesize-and-error) and  [Large File Upload Errors with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757111/large-file-upload-errors-with-php) but neither really addressed this issue.

Anyone ever come across this? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the server crashes"?

Comment: Do the server error logs give any hints?

Comment: check max memory issues... try change memory limit up to 128M and try again... as @Jim says =P

Comment: It's definitely a memory issue. But, I don't know why.. it seems like I have plenty of memory? Here is the error.  `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20000 bytes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might be hitting the memory limit...

try increasing the `memory_limit` directive in your "php.ini"

---

or

add the following on the top of your php script,

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Comment: I receive this error (sorry I didn't mention this earlier). Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20000 bytes) -- I'm on a shared server too. So, I'm guessing I won't be able to change the memory_limit.

Comment: You can also use the php "init_set" method... edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to upload an image of size greater that 2000px using php store it in database .
Create a table and then store the image in it using BLOB-Binary Lodge Object
Use file_get_contents to get the contents of the image and then store it.
Than the server won't crash

Answer (score 0):

add this to the top of your controller that is receiving the upload

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

change the limit value as needed.